# python - html - how to change a position of a closing part of a tag / move whole section

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to change a position of a closing part of a tag by removing from one place and placing into another. I try to use BeautifulSoup but the functions seem to work on whole tags. I don't know how to move just the part of the tag like  `</div>` without destroying the the proceeding part of a tag.

**how to change a position of a closing part of a  tag**

Example:

```
html = """
    <html>
     <body>
        <div>
            <div class="A">
                <h1 id="H1">H1</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div class="B">
               </div>
           </div>    < -----   remove from here

           <div class="b1"> 

               <div class="c">
               </div>
           </div>

               < -----   place here

       </div>
     </body>
    </html>  
     """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

One of my ideas is to cut the section

```
<div class="b1"> 
      <div class="c">
      </div>
 </div>
```

and place after `<div class="B">` using the function `insert_after` but I don't know how to move the whole section in one move.

Comment: what is motive behind this? what you trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to change ranges of accordion section in a few places in a programmatic way, using some logic in a loop

Comment: Do you receive html as string from outside or generate it by yourself?

Comment: @ Pavel from outside, from a file, and then I am trying to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving that `</div>` further down, you are in effect moving the `b1` after the div after the `A` div. So you could copy the `b1` div and append it to the other div. Then delete the original one. This could be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import copy

html = """
    <html>
     <body>
        <div>
            <div class="A">
                <h1 id="H1">H1</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div class="B">
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="b1"> 
                <div class="c">
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>  
     """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div_append = soup.find('div', class_='A').find_next('div')
div_b1 = soup.find('div', class_='b1')
div_append.append(copy.copy(div_b1))
div_b1.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

This would result in the following HTML:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div class="A">
    <h1 id="H1">
     H1
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div class="B">
    </div>
    <div class="b1">
     <div class="c">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```